# How to connect to MS SQL Server database remotely by IP in Python using mssql and pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

How can I connect to MS SQL Server database remotely by IP in Python using mssql and pymssql modules.
To connect locally I use link = mssql+pymssql://InstanceName/DataBaseName

I enabled TCP/IP Network Configurations. 
But How can I get the connection link?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a `Connection` object

```
import pymssql
ip = '127.0.0.1'
database_connection = pymssql.connect(host=ip, port=1433, username='foo', password='bar')
```

If you're using SQLAlchemy, or another ORM that supports connection strings, you can also use the following format for the connection string.

```
'mssql+pymssql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}'
```

Comment: Can I generate the string for connection something like this: "mssql+pymssql://InstanceName/DataBaseName".
I thought I could just replace the string and not change the code. 
Because this string is in config file.

Comment: @VadimKovrizhkin Are you using SQLAlchemy? How are you using that string?

Comment: Yes, it is SQLAlchemy. It is legacy code. I just have this string in the config file.

Comment: @VadimKovrizhkin Then use the second chunk of code I edited in.